# java JLayeredPane how to add JPanel in front of another panel generated by Window builder

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I am writing in java some kind of application and i have to place something in front of another objects( in Z order)
I know that that i should use JLayeredPane but in fact i am not very familiar with it.
My idea is to make two JPanel's with different Z-order factors while inserting them to JLayeredPane.
i pasted my code http://www.wklejto.pl/130038
i would be very grateful if you tell me what is wrong because i am doing it for a long of time with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with this code. Maybe you're trying to paint a transparent (not opaque) `JPanel`  (e.g. with message) on top of the underlying base `JPanel`.
In that case you should invoke `setOpaque(false)` on your front `JPanel`.

```
    JPanel second = new JPanel();
    second.setOpaque(false);
    second.add(new JLabel("message"));
    jlp.add(second, new Integer(300));
```

`JPanel`s are opaque by default - on the other hand `JLabel`s aren't.

And take a look into [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).